# VB.net "'Me' is valid only within an instance method" inside PageMethods

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting "Me' is valid only within an instance method" error when I convert function to a PageMethods.

```
Private Shared objDT As System.Data.DataTable
Private Shared objDR As System.Data.DataRow

<WebMethod()> Public Shared Function addstn(itemID As String) As String
  For Each Me.objDR In objDT.Rows
            If objDR("ProductID") = ProductID Then
                If objDR("Options") = desc Then
                    objDR("Quantity") += 1
                    blnMatch = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
  Next

End Function
```

If I remove Me, I get different error.
I got this shopping cart script somewhere online and I'm not sure what to replace "Me.objDR"  with something else.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, what *would* `Me` be *not* in an instance method?

Comment: @user166390 Intuitively, in a different implementation of the language, `Me.Foo` in an instance would be `Instance.Foo`, and `Me.Foo` in a Shared would be `Class.Foo`. And `Me.Foo` when called in `Shared()` with a non-Shared `Foo` would be a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Me keyword provides a way to refer to the specific instance of a class or structure in which the code is currently executing.

In a shared context there is no instance. You can reference your variable directly or via `ClassName.VariableName`.

This could work(i'm not sure wherefrom the other variables are):

```
For Each objDR In objDT.Rows
        If ProductID.Equals(objDR("ProductID")) _
           AndAlso desc.Equals(objDR("Options"))Then
                Dim q = CInt(objDR("Quantity"))
                objDR("Quantity") = q + 1
                blnMatch = True
                Exit For
        End If
Next
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Me` cannot be used since its a shared method, shared methods are not accessed through an instance.

What is the other error you receive?

Answer (score 0):

> Public **Shared** Function addstn(...

The "Shared" means it's not an instance method. If you want to use "Me", you can't use "Shared". Use the name of the class/module instead.